# Format of url field in an AJAX call using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX request via jQuery to a PHP script present in a different server (say the IP is 11.1.35.12) and the location of PHP script is "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kibana\mytelemetry.php" inside the server. What should be the url in my below ajax code?

```
$.ajax({

    url     :   "11.1.35.12/Kibana/mytelemetry.php",
    cache   :   false,
    data    :   ({
                    DshBrdName  : strFullDashBoardName,
                    DshBrdID    : currentDashboard, 
                    r           : Math.random()
                }),
    success :   function(data, textStatus, jQxhr){
                    //alert(textStatus); 
                },
    error   :   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    //alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
    type    :   "POST"
});
```

P.S : The above is not working! I am pretty sure my url format is wrong.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `http` protocol when passing in url and your script is requesting url in the current domain you're in.

try this:

```
$.ajax({

    url     :   "http://11.1.35.12/Kibana/mytelemetry.php",
    cache   :   false,
    data    :   ({
                    DshBrdName  : strFullDashBoardName,
                    DshBrdID    : currentDashboard, 
                    r           : Math.random()
                }),
    success :   function(data, textStatus, jQxhr){
                    //alert(textStatus); 
                },
    error   :   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    //alert(textStatus);
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
    type    :   "POST"
});
```

Beside that, you have to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your php script

Comment: Can you please let me know the headers I need to add in my PHP script?

Comment: The simplest way to do this is just adding line `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` somewhere in your script. Preferably at the very beginning, because you cannot set headers after sending response (like `echo` or `var_dump()`). Also, you can (and probably should) replace `*` sign with your domain (without protocol). There's a good reading about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)